# How to create an object of type numpy.int8 in a C numpy extension?

Tags: python, numpy, cpython, python-c-api

I have created my own class in a C Python extension. I want it to behave like a numpy array.

Let's say my class is a myarray. I can index it using the slice notation. This means that my implementation of the `mp_subscript` function of the `mapping_methods` looks correct. I can further index it, and it returns the element I want, of the correct type.

```
# Create a new myarray object of 10 elements
a = myarray( 10 )
# Get a slice of this myarray, as a numpy.ndarray object
#   returns new one created with PyArray_NewFromDescr (no copy)
b = a[2:4]
# What is the class of an indexed item in the slice?
print( b[0].__class__ )
<class 'numpy.int8'>
```

I also have implemented the direct index into my own type with `a[0]`. For this, I've tried calling `PyArray_GETITEM`. But the object I have in return is of type `int`.

```
# Create a new myarray object of 10 elements
a = myarray( 10 )
# What is the class of an indexed item in the slice?
#   returns the result of calling PyArray_GETITEM.
print( a[0].__class__ )
<class 'int'>
```

How can I, within my C extension, create this object of type `numpy.int8`?

Answer (score 0):

Found out I have to call `PyArray_Scalar` for this.